# What is the best way to pass a method when I initialize an object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class which represents a mathematical model. Within this class, I have methods to solve the model, methods to print the results, etc.

The model can be solved for different functions. I am wondering what is the best way to pass a method when I initialize a python object.

To give an example, suppose I had the class `Foo` and the method `f1`. My goal is that instead of being defined inside the class definition, `f1` would be passed as a parameter.

So, I know I can do this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x1):
        self.x1 = x1

    def f1(self):
        return self.x1

bar = Foo(10)

print(bar.f1())
# Result: 10
```

But is there a way to do this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x1, f1):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.f1 = f1

def f_outside(self):
    return self.x1

bar = Foo(10, f_outside)

print(bar.f1())
# Result: 10
```

The last code example does not work. The error is: `missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Just call `self.f1(self)`. Presto!

Comment: @roganjosh, without getting into the details, the class `Foo` here represents a dynamic discrete choice model and can be solved for different "utility functions". My goal is to define the class `Foo` and without changing the code, solving for e.g. a quadratic utility function, a linear utility function, or even functions with different parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, because methods are just bound functions.

When you look up a method on an instance (such as `bar.f1`, note, no call yet) and Python finds a function by the name `f1` on the *class* (not the instance itself), then the function is bound, resulting in a method object. Python uses the [`__get__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) for this; functions define that method, and calling it with the right arguments produces a method.

When you store a function on an instance however, that doesn't happen. It's already part of an instance, it doesn't need to be bound, right? So when you use `self.f1 = f1`, no binding takes place. Calling `bar.f1()` will then fail to pass in `self` so you get an error.

But nothing stops you from binding the function yourself:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x1, f1):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.f1 = f1.__get__(self)
```

Now `bar.f1()` works, because `f1` has been bound to `bar`:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, x1, f1):
...         self.x1 = x1
...         self.f1 = f1.__get__(self)
...
>>> def f_outside(self):
...     return self.x1
...
>>> bar = Foo(10, f_outside)
>>> bar.f1()
10
```

There are other ways of achieving the same thing; you could store a function created with `lambda` to explicitly pass in `self`:

```
self.f1 = lambda: f1(self)
```

or you could use a [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) object to have it pass in `self`:

```
self.f1 = partial(f1, self)
```

or you could create a method instance from by using the type object for methods directly; there is a reference to the type via [`typing.MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodType):

```
self.f1 = MethodType(f1, self)
```

but that last one is going to achieve the exact same thing as `f1.__get__(self)`.

If you want to dive into the deep end and learn more about binding, then you want to read the [descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Answer (score 0):

You hopefully have better names in production code. Also, it'd probably make more sense to pass "x1" to the call, not to the initializer.

```
…
    def __call__(self):
        return self.f1(self.x1)
…
print(bar())
```

You can make your second thing work if you pass `self` to the callable as in `self.f1(self)` (again, design wise that'd be possibly on the smelly side).

For a better overall structure, look into the "template method" design pattern.